# Keras Input Layer Misinterpreting Input Shape

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am trying to make a very simple functional neural network in Keras. I input a vector of shape `(270000,)` to the network, and have entered this as the shape to accept in the input layer, but I receive the error shown below. Given that the shape printed for the input specified to be at fault, is in fact `(270000,)`, I don't know why I am receiving this error.

**Model Function**

```
def spectrify(A1, y1, simData, aOrigShape):
    print("A1: ", np.shape(A1))
    print("y1: ", np.shape(y1))
    print("simData", np.shape(simData))
    print("aOrigShape:", aOrigShape)
    dataIn = Input(shape=np.shape(A1))
    dataOut = Dense(np.shape(A1)[0])(dataIn)
    outShaper = Reshape((aOrigShape))(dataOut)
    model = Model(inputs = dataIn, outputs = outShaper)
    model.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop',
                 loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
                 metrics = ['accuracy'])
    model.fit(A1, simData)
    return model
```

**Execution**

Running the function above prints the shapes and raises the following error:

```
A1:  (270000,)
y1:  (200, 540)
simData (200, 400)
aOrigShape: (500, 540)

...
<ipython-input-130-88e6c1dfc1c9> in spectrify(A1, y1, simData, aOrigShape)
     12                  loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
     13                  metrics = ['accuracy'])
---> 14     model.fit(A1, simData)
     15     return model
...

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_50 to have shape (270000,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Answer (score 0):

`shape` argument refers to the shape of **one single sample** in the training data. So if you have 270000 training samples of shape `(1,)`, then the `shape` argument must be set to `(1,)`. Otherwise, which is unlikely but possible, if you have one sample of shape `(270000,)` then you need the shape argument must be set to `(270000,)` and `A` must have a shape of `(1, 270000)`, which means one sample of shape `(270000,)`, and not `(270000,)` which means 270000 samples of shape `(1,)`.

Generally, if `X_train` is the array which contains your training data, then it's a good practice to use `X_train.shape[1:]` (i.e. the shape of each sample) as the input shape, like this:

```
Input(shape=X_train.shape[1:])
```